# Date validation allows invalid dates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

Using this model:

```
public class Holiday
{
  [Required]
  public DateTime From { get; set; }
}
```

With this view:

```
@model Holiday
@using System.Web.Optimization
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Request";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Holiday Request</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.From)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.From)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.From)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

If I input text, I get an invalid date. If I leave the field empty, I get a message too. If however, I put in a date such as `2013/20/20` this is valid, how can I change this? I thought it could be something related to cultures, but this would be invalid in all cultures.

**Source HTML**

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Holiday Request</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="From">From</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field From must be a date." data-val-required="The From field is required." data-val-weekdaydate="Must be a working day" id="From" name="From" type="datetime" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="From" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since we're talking about JavaScript, please show the _rendered_ HTML output as well as any jQuery code.

Comment: @Sparky this is from the out of the box validation the bulk of the content is in `jQuery.Validation`, I will post it but I can't see how that is going to help anybody :)

Comment: @Sparky see my edit for the output

Comment: What happens if you put in a date like 2013/04/16? Does that work? Seems like you're running into problems that result from how DateTime.Parse or DateTime.TryParse is implemented. Perhaps you need to do some of your own custom parsing and/or validating before you throw ValidationMessageFor at it.

Comment: The html you posted works exactly as expected. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtzv2/). If you put `2013/20/20` in the date field, you get a validation error. But what is `data-val-weekdaydate`? I don't see that anywhere in the validation plugin and I'm looking at the latest source for jQuery.Validate and jQuery.validate.unobtrusive. Is that a custom validation method? Where is your source for it?

Comment: Interesting, the validation appears to work correctly in Chrome 26.0, but Firefox 19.0 is letting it go through.

Comment: @LukeHennerley, The rendered HTML is the only thing that JavaScript can see, therefore, it's the only thing that matters when solving a JavaScript issue.

Answer (score 0):

This appears that it might be some sort of issue (hint: feature) in Firefox and possibly IE (I'm currently running 20.0.1 and IE8). The relevant code from jQuery validation is this:

```
date: function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
}
```

using `new Date()` to check the date's validity.

If I put `new Date("2020/20/20")` into the console, it returns a valid date of `Date {Fri Aug 20 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)}`. In other words, it "rolled over" the months from 20 to 8 (20-12 = 8...August).

But if I enter the date as `new Date("2020-20-20")` with <kbd>-</kbd> instead of <kbd>/</kbd>, date parsing works correctly and I get `Date {Invalid Date}`. If you're ok with enforcing a strict yyyy-MM-dd format on your date field, then fixing this is pretty simple. Just override the date function like so:

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || 
        (/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$/.test(value) &&
        !(/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))));   
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JutnA/)

Basically, I just added a simple regex to make sure that the value entered is in dddd-dd-dd format (with the <kbd>-</kbd> character). If that passes, the result is passed along to the browser for date validation. It's not a great solution, but I think enforcing the format of the date isn't necessarily a bad thing since it promotes consistency. You can change the regex around however you need to, such as `\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}`, but i think the trick is to enforce the <kbd>-</kbd>.

Comment: I want my dates to be valid UK dates. I have hit the same problem when implementing a new validation method in that it is always going to US date format in jQuery - `mm/DD/yyyy`.

Comment: Well then the same concept applies, but in the overridden date method you can create a regex `d{2}/d{2}/d{4}` and then perform string operations to parse out the day, month, and year. Then pass that into the `Date(yyyy, mm, dd)` constructor. If they entered a valid date, it will pass.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `moment.js` to tweak the `date` validation method `jQuery.validation.js`, it now looks like this:

```
date: function (value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || moment(value, "DD-MM-YYYY").isValid();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryvalidation.org/date-method
"This method should not be used, since it relies on the new Date constructor, which behaves very differently across browsers and locales."

When I use MVC Scaffolding I add
to the POCO as well as:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")] 

if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.datetime) {
    $("input[type='datetime']").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" });
}
```

The jQuery page above has a sample, showing Luke's and my date taste does not work with jquery.validate.js; Thanks for the tweak Luke!