# Custom weekday date validation needs to implement or recognise cultures

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This **is** in a way similar to my question yesterday in that it is related to the formats and formatting of `Date` types when it comes to browsers.

[Date validation allows invalid dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040773/date-validation-allows-invalid-dates)

I am getting to grips with `jQuery`, `Javascript` and `MVC` which may be why I am hitting brick walls constantly as I can't understand what to do next. I am creating a simple holiday request application. A request date needs to be a weekday.

I followed through [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422573/Model-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC) yesterday and here is what I have.

```
public class WeekdayAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
  public override bool IsValid(object value)
  {
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out dt))
      return dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday;
    else
      return false;
  }

  public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
  {
    yield return new ModelClientValidationRule()
    {
      ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage,
      ValidationType = "weekdaydate"
    };
  }
}
```

I then have the following in `jQuery.validate.unobtrusive`

```
$jQval.addMethod("weekdaydate", function(value, element, params) {
  var day = new Date(value).getDay();
  return day != 0 && day != 6;
});
```

The functionality of this works fine in the sense that if I input a invalid `US` date, it will validate fine and present a message. It is however ignoring that my machine and browser is `UK`, similar to the validation in my previous question (which seems to just allow `*/*/*` where * is a number).

My question is, is there a way to force my dates to be `UK` format across the whole of MVC website? How can I force `UK` formats?

Comment: You may give a look at momentjs, a nice library to easily manipulate dates with javascript : see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ and http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

Comment: @jbl I have used this, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@jbl's` commment was a great shout. I have modified the `date` validation in `jquery.validation.js` to be as follows:

```
$jQval.addMethod("weekdaydate", function(value, element, params) {
  var day = new moment(value, "DD-MM-YYYY").day();
  return day != 0 && day != 6;
});
```